# Simple mod_rewrite rules not working

Tags: mod-rewrite

In trying to get my head around mod_rewrite, I've added a simple rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^z$ z1.html
```

The idea is to let someone access `www.mysite.com/z` and have them get `www.mysite.com/z1.html`

But this doesn't work. I have to change it to

```
RewriteRule ^/z$ /z1.html
```

But I'm not seeing anything in the mod_rewrite rules that requires a "/" in front of the terms, so why doesn't the first one work?

A bit more complicated, I have the rule

```
RewriteRule ^/([^.]+)$ /1$.html
```

and this one doesn't work either, even with the "/" characters.

The idea here is to let some enter `www.mywebsite.com/z1` and have it become `www.mywebsite.com/z1.html`.

Does anyone see the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have mod rewrite rules in vhost/server config, it requires a `/` as part of the pattern. The second rule doesn't work because you want `$1`, and not `1$`:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^.]+)$ /$1.html [L]
```